# Cannot view image using image_view on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros indigo installed on ubuntu 14.04. When I run the command

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/cam1/image_raw
```

I get the error

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/image_view/image_view: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I get past this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194941/cannot-view-image-using-image_view-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [takb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20395/takb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like image_view is trying to load an old library. Are you sure all of your packages are up to date?

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1